# Dynamic MmongoDB schema

Tags: javascript, backend, schema, mern

I want to create a new schema each time I send JSON data in the API with that JSONn. I don't understand how to do this. I want to do this in the mern or nest whatever is easy. I will create a dynamic endpoint for the new data and store the information in the new schema according to the JSON data coming.

I can make the dynamic endpoint with the id but how can I create the schema?

```
app.post('/dynamic/:id', (req, res) => {
  const dynamicId = req.params.id;
  const jsonData = req.body; // The incoming JSON data

  // Store the JSON data in MongoDB as a schema-less document
  // ...

  res.status(200).send('Data successfully processed and stored.');
});
```